# Lectura-escritura de fichero en C con array

Tags: c

Almacenaría de esta forma los precios del .txt en el array ?
El fgets se utiliza más para caracteres o cadenas ?

```c
FILE *f;
int x;
float vPrecio[100];
f = fopen("precios.txt", "r");
if (f==NULL){
    printf("\nNo se ha podido abrir el fichero");
}else{
```

[image: Tarea:(]

Comment: ,si porfa, edita tu pregunta y añade tu código

Comment: los prototipo no es un intento significativo, aquí no estamos para hacer tareas, estamos para ayudar a resolver problemas. Por favor muestra tu intento real.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es tu problema? que hace ese codigo? que le falla?

Comment: ¿Que error te sale?, la porción de código realmente no nos cuenta nada. Te recomiendo que nos digas en la pregunta que error te sale y una porción de codigo mas significativa.

Answer (score 0):

El fgets sirve para cadenas, es mas usado para escribir en archivos. En la forma que estas haciendo si podrias almacenar precios, pero solo en el arreglo y no en el archivo, ademas de que no esta en el formato correcto ya que la r es de lectura y para escribir es con w. Para que se escriba en el archivo usa la funcion fprintf. Recuerda cerrar tu archivo!!!